# Can I make colours 'web safe' (216 color palette) with CSS only?

Tags: css, colors

For a retro themed project I want to get colors showing in the web safe color scheme.

I can re-edit my images to make them use the 216 color palette of old but I would prefer to keep them as is and emulate web safe colors in CSS.

I have tried fiddling the brightness of an image to be losing some color fidelity and then trying to bring it back with a container element, e.g.:

```
<figure style="filter: brightness(100);">
    <img src="/example.jpg" style="filter: brightness(0.01);">
 </figure>
```

This gets me half the way there but what numbers would I need to get this right for emulating 'web safe' colours?

I am not that fussed on 216 colours, 256 will do fine, but how can I emulate it in CSS?

Comment: Really what you need to do is alter each pixel to it's nearest "web safe" equivalent. You could use something like this method here: https://css-tricks.com/manipulating-pixels-using-canvas/

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of adjustment this gives me the effect I was after:

```
figure:hover {
    filter: brightness(16);
}

figure:hover > * {
    filter: brightness(0.0625);
}
```

0.0625 is 1/16.

So why 16?

16 is 5 bits in binary. So I am dropping 5 of the 8 bits in each colour channel.

With three bits per colour channel that means 9 bits, one more than 8 for 8 bit colour. But the effect is only for retro looks, not strict emulation.